# Finding totals of certain strings in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, subtotal

I have two arrays, one with tax codes (emptaxdeductcode), and one with the amounts paid for those tax codes (emptaxamt).

I am trying to find the amounts paid for *only the tax codes ending in 31*. These tax codes have different number of characters, but the ones I need are always 12 characters.

Trying to use a simple for loop but it appears to be breaking at line 3. It's always showing 0 even for those that have the tax code(s) in question:

```
var returnedValue = 0;
for (var q = 0; q < emptaxdeductcode.length; q++) {
    if (emptaxdeductcode[q].substring(10,11) == "31") {
        returnedValue += emptaxamt[q];
    } else {
        0;
    }
}
returnedValue;
```

I've tried the following just as a test and it is returning true:
(This tax code isn't always in [5] so I can't just use that. Plus there are people who have multiple tax codes ending in 31)

```
if (emptaxdeductcode[5].substring(10,11) == "31") {
    "TRUE";
} else {
    "FALSE";
}
```

So it must be the substring within the for loop that is causing problems. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here is a sample of the data. Apologies if this exports strangely - not exactly sure how to make tables:

emptaxdeductcode    |   emptaxamt

--- |   ---

00-10   |   55.36

00-11   |   8.33

00-12   |   35.63

39-20   |   17.64

39-22   |   0.40

390770040-31    |   9.48

390770040-32    |   2.00

Edit2: This software I am using to build this report does not support many JS utilities/libraries. A lot of posts on stackoverflow with similar issues to me have been resolved with 'prototype' functions or AngularJS and things like that. Unfortunately that won't work for me.

Comment: How does it break at line 3?

Comment: try logging the value of emptaxdeductcode[q] before processing it and see what it was before the error. emptaxdeductcode can contain any null value?

Comment: can you show how your data looks like?

Comment: @epascarello - by breaking, i mean It's just not giving me the data I need. Its always returning zero when it shouldn't.

Comment: @TheReason I edited my post to show a sample of the data for one employee.

Comment: @alebianco emptaxdeductcode is never null for this particular thing I am working on. I suppose it's possible for emptaxamt[x] to be 0, but not null.

Comment: as @chris-b mentioned, the check with substring(10,11) could not ever match, because that resolves to just "3" (for the _right_ tax codes) and that does not equal to 31

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issue is that you're only reading 1 character from the string using substring rather than 2.

I think you want

```
emptaxdeductcode[q].substring(10,12)
```

instead.

Here is some sample code and a JSFiddle.

```
var emptaxdeductcode = ["123451234531", "123451234532"];
var emptaxamt = [10, 20];

var returnedValue = 0;
for (var q = 0; q < emptaxdeductcode.length; q++)
{
    if (emptaxdeductcode[q].substring(10,12) == "31") {
        returnedValue += emptaxamt[q];
    } else {
        0;
    }
}
alert(returnedValue);
```

[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/mpj3ja2j/)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I went and tried this - no bueno, unfortunately. Even changing it to just substring(10) doesn't work.

Comment: Very strange. It works perfectly in the jsFiddle. Try logging the output of that to the console in your app.

console.log(emptaxdeductcode[q].substring(10,12));

Tell us what you get.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
console.log(emptaxdeductcode[q].substring(10, 11));
```

you will see that you get back `3`, not `31`. So you need to bump it to 12.

```js
var emptaxdeductcode = ["00-10", "00-11", "00-12", "39-20", "39-22", "390770040-31", "390770040-32"],
  emptaxamt = [55.36, 8.33, 35.63, 17.64, 0.40, 9.48, 2.00];

var returnedValue = 0;
for (var q = 0; q < emptaxdeductcode.length; q++) {
  if (emptaxdeductcode[q].substring(10, 12) == "31") {
    returnedValue += emptaxamt[q]
  }
}

console.log(returnedValue);
```

I personally would either use

```
var code = emptaxdeductcode[q].substr(-2);
```

or

```
var code = emptaxdeductcode[q].split("-").pop();
```

```js
var emptaxdeductcode = ["00-10", "00-11", "00-12", "39-20", "39-22", "390770040-31", "390770040-32"],
  emptaxamt = [55.36, 8.33, 35.63, 17.64, 0.40, 9.48, 2.00];


var total = emptaxdeductcode.reduce( function(total, code, ind){
    if (code.split("-").pop() === "31") {
      total += emptaxamt[ind];  
    }
    return total;
}, 0);

console.log(total);
```